# how to add 2 fraction number usiing fraction.js library in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var min=math.format(math.fraction("-5 1/2"));
console.log(min);
var max=math.format(math.fraction("4 1/2"));
console.log(max);
var i=min;
console.log(i);
var j=0;
j=math.format(math.add(min,i));// i am getting problem here
console.log(j);
```

how to add 2 fraction numbers.How can i add min & i

Answer (score 0):

Math.js [format function documentation](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/format.html):

> **Function format**
>
> Format a value of any type into a string.

Math.js [add function documentation](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/format.html):

> **Function add**
>
> Add two or more values, x + y. For matrices, the function is evaluated element wise.
>
> [...]
>
> **Parameters**
>
> Parameter: x
>
> Type: number | BigNumber | Fraction | Complex | Unit | Array | Matrix

The problem here is that `math.format` returns a string but `math.add` expects values as parameters.

Instead of formatting min and max right away, you could format them inside your `console.log` calls like so:

```
const a = math.fraction('1/2');
const b = math.fraction('3/4');

const c = math.add(a, b);

console.log(math.format(a));
console.log(math.format(b));
console.log(math.format(c));
```